# Working out Thévenin voltage with no voltage source

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current-source, thevenin

How do I get the Thévenin voltage having worked out the load impedance and obtained it as 3.415 - j0.7317 Ω?

[image]

Comment: How can you search for similar answers to similar questions if you treat each part as Zn then sub actual in later since this is Complex domain x+jy but for DC you can block with C and simplify by dropping ‘y’

Comment: I meant dropping negative j items as these are insulators to DC (caps) not +j parts which are conductors of DC(inductors)

Comment: \$V_{TH}\$ Is the voltage across the load terminals with the load removed.

Comment: Use source transformation to convert the `6 A` and the `-j4 ohm` and the `8 ohm` to a voltage source. Then you will have a voltage source and only a single loop in the circuit.

Comment: Is the 6A DC?                    .................................

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Thévenin voltage by turning the current source on and letting Zl go open.
After a long time the capacitors act as open and the inductors as short.

Note: You should check your Thévenin impedance calculation, you appear to have made an error there.

Comment: am actually confident about my calculation of the thevenin  impedance,i believe its right,,

Comment: Does the imaginary part make sense to you?

Comment: it does,,its ac circuit not dc,,,

Comment: And you reckon that it is capacitive?

Comment: the thevenin impedance is inductive, the value i indicated is the load impedance which is equal to the complex conjugate of the thevenin impedance

Answer (score 0):

The current source schematic symbol should be for an AC source at a constant frequency, otherwise the given values of the capacitor and inductor make no sense.

The Thevenin value of the four leftmost components is a 48-j24 volt source with an 8+j6 ohm Thevenin impedance. Merging the 5 ohm resistor into the Thevenin equivalent changes the voltage source to (48+j24)*5/(13+j6) and makes the Thevenin impedance 5 ohms in parallel with 8+j6 ohms.

Comment: Using a dc current source with capacitors and inductors is acceptable. We will find that the the Thevenin voltage is also dc.

Comment: That's true, but it wasn't that kind of problem. With 0.0 frequency (Hz, radians/sec, whatever) how could the capacitor be -j4 ohms or the inductor j10 ohms? Whoever wrote the problem used the wrong symbol.